# LINQ: find items in a list that have frequency = 1

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling with the following task. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have a list of Person objects like below:

```
public class Person {
     private string firstname {get; set}
     private string lastname {get; set}
     private string zipcode {get; set;}
     private string id {get; set;}
     private int freq = 1;

     public Person(...) {...}
}

List<Person> PersonList = new List<Person>; //Gets populated with Person objects
```

I want to find all the people who have unique names within their zipcode.

So far, I've tried performing a frequency count on all the distinct combinations of (firstname, lastname, zipcode) and then selecting the combinations that have frequency = 1. However, I then lose all information about these peoples' IDs. I need a way to retain the original Person objects despite the grouping operation.

Below is the frequency count I mentioned above, but it isn't the result I'm looking for:

```
var QueryFreqAnalysis =
                        from p in PersonList
                        group p by new { p.firstName, p.lastName, p.zipcode } into g
                        select new {
                            fName = g.Key.firstname,
                            lName = g.Key.lastname,
                            zip3 = g.Key.zipcode,
                            freq = g.Sum(p => p.freq)
                        };
```

As I mentioned, even though I can now select groups within g that have freq = 1, I have lost all information about the Person IDs.

I hope I've made the problem clear. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from p in PersonList
// Group by name and zip
group p by new { p.firstName, p.lastName, p.zipcode } into g
// Only select those who have unique names within zipcode
where g.Count() == 1
// There is guaranteed to be one result per group: use it
let p = g.FirstOrDefault()
select new {
    fName = p.firstname,
    lName = p.lastname,
    zip3 = p.zipcode,
    id = p.id
}
```

Comment: I would suggest replacing the select new ... with just select p;

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted- thanks so much for your generous assistance! I was not aware of the FirstOrDefault() function... very helpful!

Comment: Erez Robinson: btw, I removed the "freq" field from the Person object and used your suggestion to replace "select new..." with "select p". Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I know you probably only need and want a linq answer :) 
But i just had to write a non linq one:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Person>(PersonList.Count);

        var uniqueList = new List<Person>();

        foreach (var p in PersonList)
        {
            var key = p.firstname + p.lastname + p.zipcode;
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
                dict.Add(key, p);
            else
                dict[key] = null;
        }

        foreach (var kval in dict)
        {
            if (kval.Value != null)
                uniqueList.Add(kval.Value);
        }

        return uniqueList;
```

Using Hash Codes is also possible.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm going with the LINQ solution posted by StriplingWarrior, but I appreciate your help as well :)